# Error using + Matrix dimensions must agree. in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, dot-product

I seem to have a really stupid problem but I cannot figure it out.
I have this expression in matlab

`ref_phys = @(x,y, csi) B(x,y) *  csi + b(x,y);`

On my laptop everything is fine, but moving it into another system which runs a 2016 version of Matlab, I get

```
Error using +
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in L2_proj_2D>@(x,y,csi)B(x,y)*csi+b(x,y) (line 39)
    ref_phys = @(x,y, csi) B(x,y) *  csi + b(x,y);
```

And since nothing has changed from my laptop code, I'm 100% sure that the matrix dimenions agree.

B(x,y) has dymension 2-by-2
csi has dimension 2-by-3
b(x,y) has dimension 2-by-1

Thus everything should give a 2-by-3 matrix

Could it be the version of matlab? How can I solve it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Matlab R2016a or R2016b? Implicit expansion began in R2016b. If you are using R2016a that would explain the error

Comment: This is a change in R2016b: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/

Comment: Probably this is the problem then! I'll try to do a normal function instead of an handle. Thank you

Comment: use `repmat` to expand matrices

Comment: Why should I expand the matrices ?

Comment: You could also use bsxfun: ref_phys = @(x,y, csi) bsxfun(@plus,B(x,y) *  csi , b(x,y));